# Cannot clone git repository setup using filesystem permissions but can ssh

Tags: permissions, ssh, git

I've set up a local git server on Ubuntu 12.04.  The repos can be cloned locally on the server, but I cannot clone the repo from another server.  I can ssh to the server with the same config.

~/.ssh/config (client)

```
Host i-git
        HostName myhost
        User git
        IdentityFile %d/.ssh/i_git_id_rsa
        #LogLevel DEBUG3
```

Running:

```
ssh i-git
```

Works well.

Running:

```
git clone i-git:/home/git/test.git
```

seems to just hang.

Debug output (uncomment *LogLevel* in ~/.ssh/config):

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY  
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename ***<localuser>***/.ssh/known_hosts
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'  
debug3: key_read: missing keytype  
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts  
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename ***<localuser>***/.ssh/known_hosts 
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts  
debug2: no key of type 0 for host ***myhost***  
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename <localuser>/.ssh/known_hosts2  
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename ***<localuser>***/.ssh/known_hosts  
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'  
debug3: key_read: missing keytype  
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts  
debug2: no key of type 2 for host ***myhost***
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu seems to support 3 different types of *HostKey* values.  On the server, I see:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

If I change this to:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

Then remove the entry (in ~/.ssh/known_hosts) on the client for the host, it will now use the dsa key.  Trying to ssh:

```
ssh i-git
```

Will revalidate the server, then the git commands will all work like a charm.  For some reason, git doesn't seem to recognize the *ecdsa_key*

Hope this helps someone...